# WebRequest for Google Blogger Returned Unauthorized Exception While Posting feeds to blogger in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, blogger

I tried the below code this returned Unauthorized exception while posting new feeds to google blogger..

```
var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
    new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/4310477689444728962/posts"));
http.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXX");
http.Accept = "application/json";
http.ContentType = "application/json";
http.Method = "POST";
http.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization]
    = "Bearer" + "AIzaSyC-o1Y7Oluso7SrZuoy3JjuRfDHsoCEEsg";

var vm = new {
    kind = "blogger#post",
    blog = new { id = "4310477689444728962" },
    title = "Testtitle", content = "testcontent"
};

var dataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();

string parsedContent = dataString;
//ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] bytes1 = encoding.GetBytes(parsedContent);

Stream newStream =await http.GetRequestStreamAsync();
newStream.Write(bytes1, 0, bytes1.Length);
newStream.Dispose();

var response =await http.GetResponseAsync();

var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var sr1 = new StreamReader(stream);
var content = sr1.ReadToEnd();
```